# c++ - char const * const * - <error reading characters of string>

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants

I have a variable that is a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant char.

```
char const * const * words;
```

I then add the word "dog" to that variable.

```
words = (char const * const *)"dog";
```

However, when when I debug the code, it states this about words:

```
{0x616d7251 Error reading characters of string.}
```

*My question is*, how would I properly access the characters of that variable to the point where I can record each individual character of the string.

Here is some example code below:

```
char const * const *words;
words = (char const * const *)"dog";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    char c = (char)words[i]; // Gives me, -52'i symbol', 'd', and then '\0'
    // How do I access the 'o' and 'g'?
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>> words = { "dog" };`

Comment: @pm100 Have his programming colleagues hang him in effigy?

Comment: So `words` points to the 1000 large malloc'd buffer.  Then `words` is assigned to point "dog", with bad cast to make it happen.  This code is very broken.

Comment: @manni66 I unfortunately need to use the char const * const * words variable.

Comment: @pm100 I am just trying to be able to access a series of words through the variable 'words' but cannot seem to access the characters to do so.

Comment: _I unfortunately need to_ why?

Comment: btw you are missing a chance to add even more stars: `char * const * const *words;` is also valid

Comment: words only contains one word - 'dog'

Comment: @Eljay and of course if leaks the malloc'ed data

Comment: you also contradict yourself . You say "{0x616d7251 Error reading characters of string.}" , then later "// Gives me, -52'i symbol', 'd', and then '\0'". Which is it?

Comment: @manni66 sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Your program has undefined behavior. To remove the undefined behavior use:

```
char const * word = "dog";
for (int i = 0; i < std::strlen(word); ++i)
{
    char c = word[i];
}
```

or

```
char const * word = dog;
char const * const *words = &word;
for (int i = 0; i < std::strlen(*words); ++i)
{
    char c = (*words)[i];
}
```

#### Long answer:

You are forcing a cast from `char const*` to `char const* const*` and treating the location of memory that was holding `char`s as though it is holding `char const*`s. Not only that, you are accessing memory using an out of bounds index.

Let's say the string `"dog"` is held in some memory location as (it takes four bytes that includes the null character) and give it an address.

```
a1
|
v
+---+---+---+----+
| d | o | g | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

You can treat the address `a1` as the value of a pointer of type `char const*`. That won't be a problem at all. However, by using:

```
words = (char const * const *)"dog";
```

You are treating `a1` as though it is holding objects of type `char const*`.

Let's assume for a moment that you have a machine that uses 4 bytes for a pointer and uses little endian for pointers.

`words[0]` evaluates to a pointer. Its value will be:

```
 'd' in decimal +
 256 * 'o' in decimal +
 256*256 * 'g' in decimal +
 256*256*256 * '\0' in decimal.
```

After that, you truncate that value to `char`, which will give you back the character `d`, which is not too bad. The fun part (undefined behavior) begins when you access `words[1]`.

`words[1]` is same as `*(words+1)`. `words+1` evaluates to a pointer whose value is the address `a2`.

```
                 a2
                 |
                 v
+---+---+---+----+
| d | o | g | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

As you can see, it points to memory that is beyond what the compiler allocated for you. Dereferencing that pointer is cause for undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the very descriptive explanation. It helped put things into perspective. So with that all being said, does that mean words can only technically hold a single address to word? Or could it hold multiple?

Comment: @aromans, it could certainly wold pointers to multiple words. E.g `char const* word1 = "dog"; char const* word2 = "kittens"; char const* words[2] = {word1, word2};`.

Comment: @S Rahu, is there any possibility to pass words as a value/parameter like char const * const * that passed all words rather than just a single word?

Comment: @aromans, you can. But you also have to pass another value that indicates how many elements  are there in that array or pass a sentinel pointer value of `NULL`.

Comment: *For the size_t value I use strlen*. That does not sound right. If you have further questions, it will be better to post another question with a suitable [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

maybe you mean this

```
char const * const words = "dog";

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(words); ++i)
{
    char c = words[i]; 
}
```

now of course in c++ code you should realy be using std::string

Comment: @pm100 Still did not quite work. To be more  clear, the debugger states that 'words' has an error reading characters of string. And then when doing so, it gives me characters as such: -52 'i symbol', 'd', '\0'.

I've never used a variable as such, so a lot of what I am doing is just to find out how it works.

Comment: you are right, I swear I tested it but now doesnt compile. Fixed

Comment: But OP said in comment "I unfortunately need to use the char const * const * words variable."

Answer (score 1):

You are consistently missing the second `*`.

Ignoring the `const` stuff, you are declaring a `char** word`, which is a pointer to a pointer to a single char. You won't get a word or many words into that, and casting just hides the problem.

To get `"dog"` accessible through such a pointer, you need to take an extra step; make a variable that contains `"dog"`, and put its address into your `word`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even realize that, it just clicked! I have it working now, again thank you so much!